What mechanism can I use to create this type of motion?
I’m trying to create this type of maze for my school open day, but I’m lost on how to create this type of fluid, rocky motion
Original video at approx 18:14: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pi8anJJ2FJ8
Description: so each person would stand on one of the sides, and be able to easily lift/tilt the maze so the ball rolls. But how can I get that type of motion- I’ve gone for very light materials like polystyrene and balsa wood for the construction.
Budget: school project, so quite small. Going for a 1mx1m maze


ball and socket joint with shock absorbers.

If its too light it might not be sturdy enough for people to be fighting over which way to tilt. 3+ gas springs might be good enough (some come with ball and socket joints too).

It could be one single spring, think playground devices for kids.
But if that maze is very light weight, maybe ignore any kind of mechanism and have each participant hold one edge or corner. Holding the thing and supporting its weight by hand becoming part of that cooperative game, similar to Froebel tower cooperative game

(source)

This is a much simpler and easier idea than the gimbal!

Two different rotation mounts, one mounted to the other.  I think you are looking for something like a Gimbal:

https://www.spolearninglab.com/curriculum/lessonPlans/science/engineering/gimbal.html
https://www.daviddarling.info/encyclopedia/G/gimbal.html
https://i0.wp.com/apollo11space.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/Apollo-IMU-1.jpg?w=500&ssl=1

But instead of circular mounts, for construction simplicity you could do rectangular mounts, and you only need two axes, not three as in some of these images.
Here is one example I sketched - I'm sure this can be designed much better, and the axles needs to be able to handle the weight of a tabletop, but this is a first rev to get the idea out:

(please forgive the low quality sketch!)
You'll need to figure out the details! I'm sure some Mech Engineers would know of or imagine much better mechanisms, but this is the first one I thought of.

A ball+socket joint, as commented above, might work but might be difficult to make for cheap, out of wood, that would also handle the force and weight.
I suspect you might need a metal ball+socket, which probably increases expense significantly.
But Perhaps an expert carpenter could suggest how to make one out of wood, like this but larger so it can handle the (a) weight and (b) force:

http://workshop.electronsmith.com/content/making-wooden-ball-joint/

You may need to place bumpers (eg. rubber or carpet covered blocks) to stop the motion before it hits the floor.
